# Grabbing specific sections of text from a string

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I've got a string that I need to grab two section out - they vary as it's a PHP language file. Hoping someone can help, the string is:

```
$_LANG['FIELD1'] = "FIELD2";
```

I need to grab FIELD1 and FIELD2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
# space seperated
$ sed -n "s/.*_LANG\['\([^']*\)'] = .\(\w*\).*/\1 \2/p" file
FIELD1 FIELD2

# newline seperated 
$ sed -n "s/.*_LANG\['\([^']*\)'] = .\(\w*\).*/\1\n\2/p" file
FIELD1
FIELD2
```

Or using `grep` with [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=_LANG\[')[^']*" file
FIELD1

$ grep -Po '(?<=_LANG\[.FIELD1.\] = ")[^"]*' file
FIELD2
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's removing everything. I get zero output

Comment: @cbcp The solution is tested so I suspect the actual file is slightly different from the example in some way so post the actual file.

Comment: here's an example:
    $_LANG['all'] = "All";

Comment: Ah yeah I wrote $LANG_ that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "[\"']" '{ print $2, $4 }' file
```